# How do I check if a word is at the end of a string?

Tags: c#, regex

I learnt Regex today and made a quick expression.

```
([\s]+\(?fe?a?t(?:uring)?\.?[\s]*)
```

This matches the 'featuring' part of a song filename.

e.g.

**Artist - Title featuring 2ndArtist**

or

**Artist - Title ft 2ndArtist**

or

**Artist - Title feat. 2ndArtist**

What can I add to my expression to stop it matching a filename such as :

**Artist - I have cold feat**

?

Comment: This is answered many times already (and obviously provided in documentation), but someone will give you copy-paste ready answer soon...

Comment: Just add `(?!$)` to the end of the regex. It could be improved further though

Comment: Thanks a lot 4castle, how would I extend this to not capture white space?

Answer (score 0):

I’d better use the [String.EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that purpose. And you can use `Trim()` method to remove all white spaces:

```
bool result = myString.Trim().EndsWith(”Artist”);
```

Comment: "Artist", "Title" and "2ndArtist" are just placeholders; the actual names will not be known in advance.  OP is using the word "featuring" (or abbreviation of same) to locate the additional artist names, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You could 'anchor' your pattern to the end of the line, but you have to be careful using wildcard matches like .* before the anchor.

Another way of looking at it, what you 'do' want to match is 'featuring' in the middle.  So characters, a single space, 'featuring', single space, then some characters. So I would construct my regex like this:

```
var pattern = @"(.*) (ft\.?|feat\.?|featuring) (.*)";
```

Which will give a match broken down into 3 parts, or for a whole match only:

```
var pattern = @"(.* (?:ft\.?|feat\.?|featuring) .*)";
```

Note the @ before a string avoids the need to escape the backslashes.